# Genera PDF con JS

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Buen dia estimados.

Cuento con mi librea jspdf para generar .pdf mi pregunta es como puedo generar un pdf con imagen de fondo, algo parecido a marca de agua y sobre dicha imagen quiero que aparezca mi información, ¿Qué propiedad necesito para lograrlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Mira también [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).

Comment: si usas un table dale la imagen como background